# Rails sum on AssociationRelation attribute is incorrect if association has limit clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, arel

I have a method that computes stats (mainly sums) on a number of float attributes in a model.

The models

```
class GroupPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :scored_rounds
  has_many :rounds, dependent: :destroy
end

class Round < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group_player
end

class ScoredRound < Round
  # STI
end
```

The method that provides stats on up to 4 float attributes that is called from a other methods, depending if I'm getting stats for one player or a group of players. An initial filter on ScoredRound is passed to the method (sr)

```
def method_stats(method,sr,grp)
  rounds = sr.where.not(method => nil)
  number_rounds = rounds.count
  won = rounds.sum(method).round(2)
  if method == :quality
    dues = grp.options[:dues] * number_rounds
  else
    dues = grp.options["#{method.to_s}_dues"] * number_rounds
  end
  balance = (won - dues).round(2)
  perc = dues > 0 ? (won / dues).round(3) : 0.0
  [self.full_name,number_rounds,won,dues,balance,perc]
end
```

3 of the 4 attributes I am summing in ScoredRounds may not be set (nil) if the player did not win that game so the rounds are filtered.

Everything worked fine until I decided to add a limit on how many rounds to use. For instance if I only wanted status for the last 25 rounds in the query passed to `method_stats` I'd call:

```
def money_stats(grp,method,limit=100)
  sr = self.scored_rounds.where.not(method => nil).order(:date).reverse_order.limit(limit)
  method_stats(method,sr,grp)
end
```

Again, I just added the limit and order clause to the query. Worked fine for all records.

If I simulate the procedure in the console with out using the above methods (or using them!) I'll get an erroneous sum

```
gp = GroupPlayer.find(123)
  GroupPlayer Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "group_players".* FROM "group_players" WHERE "group_players"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 123], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  => valid group player

sr = gp.scored_rounds.where.not(:quality => nil)
  ScoredRound Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "rounds".* FROM "rounds" WHERE "rounds"."type" IN ('ScoredRound') AND "rounds"."group_player_id" = $1 AND ("rounds"."quality" IS NOT NULL)  [["group_player_id", 123]]

  => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<ScoredRound id: 5706, player_id: 123, group_player_id: 123, event_id: 12, type: "ScoredRound", date: "2016-11-04", team: 3, tee: "White", quota: 32, front: 15, back: 15, total: 30, created_at: "2016-11-04 14:18:27", updated_at: "2016-11-04 19:12:47", quality: 0.0, skins: nil, par3: nil, other: nil>,...]

sr.count
   (1.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "rounds" WHERE "rounds"."type" IN ('ScoredRound') AND "rounds"."group_player_id" = $1 AND ("rounds"."quality" IS NOT NULL)  [["group_player_id", 123]]
  => 44

sr.sum(:quality)
   (1.0ms)  SELECT SUM("rounds"."quality") FROM "rounds" WHERE "rounds"."type" IN ('ScoredRound') AND "rounds"."group_player_id" = $1 AND ("rounds"."quality" IS NOT NULL)  [["group_player_id", 123]]
  => 354.166666666667

# Now if I add the order and limit clause

sr = gp.scored_rounds.where.not(:quality => nil).order(:date).reverse_order.limit(25)
  ScoredRound Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "rounds".* FROM "rounds" WHERE "rounds"."type" IN ('ScoredRound') AND "rounds"."group_player_id" = $1 AND ("rounds"."quality" IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY "rounds"."date" DESC LIMIT $2  [["group_player_id", 123], ["LIMIT", 25]]
  => => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [...]

sr.count
   (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "rounds" WHERE "rounds"."type" IN ('ScoredRound') AND "rounds"."group_player_id" = $1 AND ("rounds"."quality" IS NOT NULL) LIMIT $2) subquery_for_count  [["group_player_id", 123], ["LIMIT", 25]]
=> 25

sr.sum(:quality)
   (1.8ms)  SELECT  SUM("rounds"."quality") FROM "rounds" WHERE "rounds"."type" IN ('ScoredRound') AND "rounds"."group_player_id" = $1 AND ("rounds"."quality" IS NOT NULL) LIMIT $2  [["group_player_id", 123], ["LIMIT", 25]]
=> 354.166666666667

###  This is the error, it return the sum off all records, 
# not the limited???? if I use pluck and sum

sr.pluck(:quality)
=> [10.0, 11.3333333333333, 10.0, 34.0, 0.0, 7.33333333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 31.5, 0.0, 21.3333333333333, 0.0, 19.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.5, 0.0, 20.0, 10.0, 28.0, 8.0, 9.5, 0.0, 3.0, 24.0]

sr.pluck(:quality).sum
=> 254.49999999999994
```

Don't know if I found a bug in AREL or I'm doing something wrong. I tried it with just Round instead of the STI ScoredRound with the same results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice, the `SUM` results for both, with and without `LIMIT`, are the same:

```
sr = gp.scored_rounds.where.not(:quality => nil)
sr.sum(:quality)
   (1.0ms)  SELECT SUM("rounds"."quality") FROM "rounds" WHERE "rounds"."type" IN ('ScoredRound') AND "rounds"."group_player_id" = $1 AND ("rounds"."quality" IS NOT NULL)  [["group_player_id", 123]]
  => 354.166666666667

sr = gp.scored_rounds.where.not(:quality => nil).order(:date).reverse_order.limit(25)
sr.sum(:quality)
   (1.8ms)  SELECT  SUM("rounds"."quality") FROM "rounds" WHERE "rounds"."type" IN ('ScoredRound') AND "rounds"."group_player_id" = $1 AND ("rounds"."quality" IS NOT NULL) LIMIT $2  [["group_player_id", 123], ["LIMIT", 25]]
=> 354.166666666667
```

That's because `LIMIT` affects the number of rows returned by the query and `SUM` returns just one, so the function is applied for all the 44 records, not the 25 given to `LIMIT`. That's not what happens with `sr.pluck(:quality).sum` which applies only to the 25 records returned by the query.

> Don't know if I found a bug in AREL or I'm doing something wrong

Sadly, 99.9% of times is not a bug but our fault :(

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I actually found a year old post that asked about the same question and a answer that explained that limit is not really part of the query [ActiveRecord calculations on subsets or records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020161/activerecord-calculations-on-subsets-or-records).

Answer (score 0):

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb, line 75
def sum(column_name = nil)
  return super() if block_given?
  calculate(:sum, column_name)
end
```

if you call `sr.sum(:quality)` then sum take **quality** as a column name and Calculates the sum of values on a given column.